# Is there a way to know why your application was not given priority as a receiver

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to override the default incoming screen, something that I know is possible in all edition of Android as fullscreencallerid does it (and well).

If I register a receiver and start an activity, I successfully replace the view with my activity. If however I start filtering by EXTRA_STATE, the default incoming call screen appears.

I suppose what would help is somehow seeing what the hell is android thinking at that point, and why it preferred the default receiver.

Is there a way to trace application lifecycle, even if it involves some heavy tweaking (It's purely for learning purposes).

Thank you.